# Kubernetes CPU Management Policy with Windows nodes on AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to set the CPU Management Policy for my Windows node pool in AKS to be: static
Been running into a few issues and would like to know:

1. is the CPU Management policy setting available for window nodes?
2. is the dynamic config available on AKS with windows nodes?
3. what's the recommended way to set this policy on AKS?

CPU Management policy: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/

Comment: What issues have run into? It seems like upstream k8s doesn't apply the CPU and memory limits on Windows nodes due to OS limitations.

Comment: It wasn't the CPU and memory limits, it was the CPU Management policy itself, however I believe the same thing applies, it looks like CPU Management policy isn't available on Windows docker containers